# How to communicate between functions and perform functions asychronously

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming but am trying to create a PDF reader. There are two functions I have made: getting the filepath from the explorer and reading the PDF information. The current format is this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
class Main():
 
    def reader():
       filetext = open(filepath,'rb')
       PDFreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filetext)
       pageObj = reader.getPage(0)
       print(pageObj.extractText()) 
       filetext.close()
       
    def open_file():
       filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Report", filetypes=(("PDF Files","*.pdf"), ("All Files","*.*")))
       print(filepath)
       reader()

win=Tk()
win.geometry("700x300")
Label(win, text="PDF Reader", font='Arial 16 bold').pack(pady=15)

button = Button(win, text="Open", command=Main.open_file)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Essentially I am trying to make the button the GUI open the PDF and once that is finished, read the data to the PDF. I want to keep them in separate functions to understand how functions can be made separately but used together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: The `PyPDF2` project is going back to its roots. **PyPDF2==3.0.X**
> will be the last version of `PyPDF2`. Development will continue with
> `pypdf==3.1.0`.

Importing every public name from a module using a wildcard (from tkinter import *) is a bad idea, because it could lead to conflicts between names defined locally and the ones imported.

- In line 9, add argument in `reader(filepath)` function.
- In line 11, change `PdfFileReade` to `PdfReader` **<== new**
- In line 12, `reader.getPage(0)` to `PDFreader.pages[0]` **<== new**
- In line 13, change `extractText()` to `extract_text()` **<== new**
- In line 19, add class to `Main.reader(filepath)`

Snippet re-wrote script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader


class Main():
 
    def reader(filepath):
       filetext = open(filepath,'rb')
       PDFreader = PdfReader(filetext)
       pageObj = PDFreader.pages[0]
       print(pageObj.extract_text()) 
       filetext.close()
       
    def open_file():
       filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Report", filetypes=(("PDF Files","*.pdf"), ("All Files","*.*")))
       print(filepath)
       Main.reader(filepath)

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("700x300")
tk.Label(win, text="PDF Reader", font='Arial 16 bold').pack(pady=15)

button =tk.Button(win, text="Open", command=Main.open_file)
button.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Result reading pdf:

```
C:/Users/python dummy/Documents/python3_dummy/tmp_dummy/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi.pdf
 
Analog Inputs for Raspberry Pi Using the
MCP3008
Created by Michael Sklar
 
https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-
raspberry-pi
Last updated on 2022-12-01 01:50:33 PM EST
©Adafruit IndustriesPage 1 of 9
```